# Outlook Scheduled E-Mail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can one set up a scheduled e-mail via VBA to send from one of multiple sender accounts mapped to an outlook client? The post on "scheduled nad recurring email in Outlook?' describes how to do this via the  default account but I was unable to do this from another shared account that is mapped to my client.  Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try SentOnBehalfOfName http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862145.aspx

Sample code http://support2.microsoft.com/?kbid=232309

```
Sub TestSentOnBehalfOfName()

   Dim myOlApp as Outlook.Application
   Dim myItem as Outlook.MailItem

   ' Create an Outlook application object
   Set myOlApp = New Outlook.Application

   ' Creates a new MailItem form
   Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

   ' Set the "From" field
   myItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Jon Grande"

   ' Display the item
   myItem.Display

End Sub
```

Those looking for the original question and answer: [Scheduled and recurring email in Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/635094/scheduled-and-recurring-email-in-outlook)?