# Outlook 2013 macro suddenly not working anymore

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, macros, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've been using a macro to send mails when a reminder is triggerd. I used this guide to get it: [Scheduled and recurring email in Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/635094/scheduled-and-recurring-email-in-outlook)

It worked fine for a couple days but now it's not sending mails anymore. I do get the reminders but my email is not being send.

I've been searching for a solution but, unfortunately, I can't find anything that works.
I basically checked everything I could think of. I copy/pasted the code so that should be okay, and the macro settings are correct too.

I hope someone here can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug the macro, set the breakpoint on the first **If** statement, fire the reminder and then execute it step by step to find the cause of the issue.

You can set/unset breakpoint and step over the code using toolbar buttons.