# Scheduled and recurring email in Outlook? Open Dialog Box error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, scheduled-tasks, vbscript

I have done these instructions
[Scheduled and recurring email in Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/635094/scheduled-and-recurring-email-in-outlook)

Now when I try to import a calendar for example in Outlook 2016 I get an error that says

> "a dialog box is open. close it and try again"

I did not have this issue before so I think it is related.  I have tried to open close Outlook 2016 365, rebooted comp, removed the VBA code.  I still get the error.